# Query fails column_name is null when column is a char

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I'm using hibernate with sql_server, but am finding problems with the following:

```
select col_code 
from table 
where col_code is null
```

Query fails: sql error 0, SQLState S1093 The column col_code is not valid

col_code is a char(5), and reads okay from other database browsers. Its just from hibernate - Any Ideas?

Comment: Check your column mappings.

Comment: Check the database you connected.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was doing an native SQL query from Java EE/Hibernate. The SQL statement that I passed to persistence was "SELECT Count (1) From Table" and I made the mistake of including a mapping class as a parameter. COUNT(1) returns an integer, so it doesn't need to be mapped. Hope that helps.
I would check that you're mapping is right.